# Writing/Parsing multiple objects from JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

So I am trying to write a program that takes command line arguments and writes them to a JSON file for a list of students and their grades for assignments, then reads the JSON back into Java for methods to work with. It works perfectly in the case of 1 student, but I can't seem to get it to work for multiple students. First time working with JSON into Java so there are probably some mistakes in the code itself that I've overlooked. Any suggestions?

```
    public class JSONTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* First we take arguments from the command line to use as student info
     * 
     */

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter student ID: ");
    String id = input.nextLine();

    // Create JSON object. This will represent a single student
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

    // Add the info we just entered into the JSON object
    root.put("name", name);
    root.put("id", id);

    // Create JSON Array for assignments and grades
    JSONArray assignments = new JSONArray();

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter assignment name: ");
        String assignment = input.nextLine();

        // Check if user hit Enter
        if (assignment.length() == 0) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter grade for assignment: ");
        String grade = input.nextLine();

        // Create a new JSON object for every assignment
        JSONObject assgnObj = new JSONObject();
        assgnObj.put("grade", grade);
        assgnObj.put("name", assignment);
        assignments.add(assgnObj);
    }

    // add the array to the root (student) object
    root.put("assignments", assignments);
    System.out.println(root.toJSONString());
    System.out.println();

    /* Writes the JSON Object into a file called "StudentGrades.json"
     * 
     */


    File file = new File("StudentGrades.json");

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {
        writer.print(root.toJSONString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }



    /* Now we parse the JSON file we just created into regular Java objects
     * 
     */
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("StudentGrades.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String student_name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        System.out.println(student_name);

        String student_id = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
        System.out.println(student_id);

        JSONArray student_grades = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("assignments");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < student_grades.size(); i++) {
            list.add(student_grades.get(i).toString());
        }
        System.out.println(list);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

[image: Example of output]

Comment: is it solved yet?